# Pandas install requiring NumPy 1.6.1

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm having some trouble installing pandas on OS X. I've tried installing through pip:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

And get the error:

```
pandas requires NumPy >= 1.6.1 due to datetime64 dependency
```

When I fire up the python interpreter, I get this for my NumPy version:

```
import numpy
numpy.__version__
'1.7.0'
```

I've tried uninstalling numpy via pip, reinstalling 1.6.1, confirming the 1.6.1 install via the above method, and installing pandas with pip again; same error message.

I've also tried downloading the pandas-master branch and installing with

```
python setup.py
```

and received

```
install requires: 'python-dateutil < 2','numpy'.  use pip or easy_install.
   $ pip install 'python-dateutil < 2' 'numpy'
```

Any thoughts on next steps?

Comment: I had nothing but problems with numoy / scipy /pandas on OsX. You can install the python distro from Enthought, called EPD pretty easily, which includes scipy / numpy and perhaps pandas. These days I just work in a Ubuntu virtual machine. I hate OsX.

Comment: I have also had issues with OSX, pip install (of a few of the dependencies *should* work (!)). It may help to use virtualenv...

Comment: Andy – Great idea using virtualenv. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: reptilicus – If virtualenv fails, running in a virtual machine is my next step...

Comment: Not a solution, per se, but per Andy's suggestion I wound up installing and running in virtualenv. While this works out of the box in the python interpreter, I had to make iPython virtuanenv aware in order to run it in iPython Notebook: http://rodesia.org/2012/09/04/making-ipython-virtualenv-aware/

Comment: pip install and uninstall gets confused it you did manual installs as fas as I can remember.   took a while, but managed to get everything on OSX sorted so that pip install worked, been a few months ago but think I installed GCC compiler, an open source Fortran compiler.   Numpy now happily installs from pip.   names it very nice when working with virtualenv as the binary installs sometimes refuse to install into the correct virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched from Windows to OS X and had a major headache with numpy / scipy / matplotlib etc using pip.  On Windows, I *loved* the [pythonxy](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) distribution.  I finally found something similar for OS X: [Scipy Superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/).  It worked absolutely brilliantly for me and includes Pandas.